# Form submit when field value is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a form with a single input that takes the mobile number of user and validate it that begin with 0. The validation works good but the problem is when i submit the form it does not check the value of my inputbox and submit my form even if field is invalid.i want to check the validation of my field and when it was valid then can submit.

here is my code :

```js
$('#mobili').focusout(function() {
  $('#mobili').filter(function() {
    var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
    var mobiback = $('#mobili');
    var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
    if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
      $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
      $("#error-nwl").text("Enter valid mobile number (begin with 0)");
    } else {
      $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
      $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
    }
  })
});

$(".newslside").submit(function(e) {
  var url = "page2.html";
  alert("Submitted");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $(".newslside").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $(".errori").html(data),
        alert("Submitted");
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error-nwl"></div>
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm" class="newslside">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" id="mobili" maxlength="11" required />
  <br/>
  <button class="submitnews" type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: use input type submit for your button

Comment: use `return false` in `if` condition. The place where you have written the validation.

Comment: your validation should be inside `submit ` event. not out side. If it is invallied then `return false`. Else do the Ajax call

Comment: Your if condition is returning true, set it to `return false`

Comment: @AbhishekPandey how can i set my if to return false?

Comment: You are using onfocusout and this works only if the user enter the number. If he doesn't and directly click on submit your form will be posted anyway.

Comment: Alternatively if you want to use the regex just wrap the code in a function which has to return false if the number do not match and cal this function before your ajax call. Your regex also do not work.

Comment: Just a question should you not be validating inputs server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work,

```
$('#mobili').focusout(function() {
   $('#mobili').filter(function() {
   var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
   var mobiback = $('#mobili');
   var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
   if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
      $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
      $("#error-nwl").text("Enter valid mobile number (begin with 0)");
   } else {
      $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
      $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
   }
 })
});

$(".newslside").submit(function(e) {

     var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
     var mobiback = $('#mobili');
     var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
     if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
         $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
         $("#error-nwl").text("Enter valid mobile number (begin with 0)");
         return false;
     }else{
         var url = "page2.html";
         alert("Submitted");
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(".newslside").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
               $(".errori").html(data),
               alert("Submitted");
            }
         });
    }
       e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".newslside").submit(function(e) { var url = "page2.html";
  alert("Submitted");
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: $(".newslside").serialize(),
 success: function(data) { $(".errori").html(data),
   alert("Submitted");
  } }); e.preventDefault();

 }); 
  
     $('#mobili').filter(function() {
        var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
        var mobiback = $('#mobili');
        var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
        if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
            $("#error-nwl").text("Enter valid mobile number (begin with 0)");
        } else {
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
            $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error-nwl"></div>
    <form action="" method="post" name="myForm" class="newslside">
    <input pattern="[0-9]{10}" type="text" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" id="mobili" maxlength="11" required /><br/>
    <input type="submit" class="submitnews" value="Send"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used HTML's `onsubmit` attribute and this works, hope it fits for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
        var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
        if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
            $("#error-nwl").text("Enter valid mobile number (begin with 0)");
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
            $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
            var url = "page2.html";
            alert("Submitted");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(".newslside").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".errori").html(data),
                    alert("Submitted");
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="error-nwl"></div>
    <form action="" method="post" name="myForm" class="newslside"  onsubmit="return(validate());">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" id="mobili" maxlength="11" required />
        <br/>
        <button class="submitnews" type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="error-nwl"></div>
            <form action="" method="post" name="myForm" class="newslside">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" id="mobili" maxlength="11" required /><br/>
            <button class="submitnews" type="submit">send</button>
            </form>
        <script>
        var valid = false;
        function focusout()
        {
        $('#mobili').focusout(function() {
            $('#mobili').filter(function() {
                var mobi = $('#mobili').val();
                var mobiback = $('#mobili');
                var mobilReg = /^([0][0-9]{10})$/;
                if (!mobilReg.test(mobi)) {
                    $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
                    $("#error-nwl").text("Enter valid mobile number (begin with 0)");
                    valid = false;
                } else {
                    $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#66cc66');
                    $("#error-nwl").text("ok");
                    valid = true;
                }
            })
        });

        }
        focusout();
        </script>
        <script>
        $(".newslside").submit(function(e) { 
        focusout();
        if(!valid )
        {
            return false;
        }
        var url = "page2.html";
          alert("Submitted");
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: $(".newslside").serialize(),
         success: function(data) { $(".errori").html(data),
           alert("Submitted");
          } }); e.preventDefault();

         }); 
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate that field inside onsubmit function of jquery. And add return false to your form tag.